# Minimum distance

Tags: functions, derivatives

Find the point M (x, y) in the plane (xy) so that the sum of the squares of the distances of this point to the lines x = 0, y = 0 and x - y + 1 = 0 is the smallest.

I don't know how to start. Thank you for your help.

Comment: step 1) write down distances to the three lines. In general if the equation of a line is $ax + by + c = 0$, then the distance of a point $(u,v)$ to that line is $\frac{|a u + bv + c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Comment: Once you have found the distance of the point to each of the $3$ lines and you have added the squares of the distances, you may have to use calculus to find the minimum.

Comment: I compute, that point M is $(-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$, is that correct?

Comment: @julio77 yes, the minimum is at $(-1/4,1/4)$.